# loop through records in excel and update specific rows in mysql database with values from the excel file in php

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv

Hello am trying to update rows in my savings table but getting values from an excel file using a primary key as account_id which both the file and the 
table.My code does not execute like expected

```
   if(isset($_POST['import'])){
       $filename = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
       if ($filename[1]=="csv") {
           $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
           $openFile = fopen($file,'r');

           while ($dataFile = fgetcsv($openFile,3000,",")) {
               $acc = $dataFile[0];
               $amount_deposited = $dataFile[2];
               $recovered_amount = $dataFile[3];

               /*update balances */
               $insert = "UPDATE savings SET balance = balance+'$amount_deposited' WHERE account_id ='$acc'";
               $run_insert = mysql_query($insert);

               $insert = "INSERT INTO transactions values('','$acc','Saving','$recovered_amount','',now(),'')";
               $run_insert = mysql_query($insert);
          }
          echo "<div id='alert'>Successfully ADDED</div>";
       } else {
          echo "You must choose a CSV file to import";
       }
    }
```

Comment: what is your error?what you expected?

Comment: i expected the savings table to be updated with a new sum of balance after importing the csv file with the new amount deposited+the balance that was originally there

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php),
**a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world** it is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) its really pretty easy

Comment: Ok now what happening?

Comment: You said it, so why are you here?

Comment: I suggest you : Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: I suggest you also add a test of the `$run_insert` status like so `if ( ! $run_insert) { echo mysql_error(); exit;}` after each INSERT so you get to see any errors that may be happening

Comment: I also suggest you show us the code that makes the connection to your database

Comment: This is my code to the database   mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
  mysql_select_db('test');

Answer (score 0):

This worked,Thanks guys

```
              while ($dataFile = fgetcsv($openFile,3000,",")) {
               $acc = $dataFile[0];
                $amount_deposited = $dataFile[1];

               /*update balances */

               $insert = "UPDATE savings SET balance = balance+".intval($amount_deposited)." WHERE account_id ='$acc'";
               $run_insert = mysql_query($insert);

              $insert2 = "INSERT INTO trans values('','$amount_deposited',now(),'$acc')";
               $run_insert = mysql_query($insert2);
               }
              echo "<div id='alert'>Successfully ADDED</div>";
            }
            else{
              echo "You must choose a CSV file to import";
            }
          }
```